# Html.ActionLink as a button or an image, not a link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

In the latest (RC1) release of ASP.NET MVC, how do I get Html.ActionLink to render as a button or an image instead of a link?

Comment: With MVC 3.0 you can try this way <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Themes/Gold/images/try-onit.png")" alt="Home" /></a> More info, Try this http://mycodingerrors.blogspot.com/2012/08/actionlink-with-image-in-aspnet-mvc-3.html

Comment: Having just spent a few hours doing this "properly" (e.g. by extending `AjaxHelper` with an `ActionButton`) I thought I would share it below.

Comment: It's hilarious to me that seven years later, this question is still getting upvotes.  Apparently in 2016 there's still no simple, intuitive way to do this.

Answer (score 335, accepted):

Late response but you could just keep it simple and apply a CSS class to the htmlAttributes object.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Button Name", "Index", null, new { @class="classname" }) %>
```

and then create a class in your stylesheet

```
a.classname
{
    background: url(../Images/image.gif) no-repeat top left;
     display: block;
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
     text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me, though you may need to replace null with a routeValues object depending on where you are linking to.

Comment: How do you handle the Button name string you assign in the action link parameter then. This did not work for me.

Comment: Same problem, for me too, the linkText param can't be null or and empty string however I'm looking for an image button replacment.

Comment: For SEO and Accessibility you would need the link button text.. i've updated the CSS in the question to handle this...

Comment: It works perfect but this button image doesnt appears in the print of the webpage.

Comment: that is bad in all sorts of ways, it dose not work in all browsers, and you are using a side effect as functionality. witch makes it a very bad practice don't use it. Just because it works it does not make it a good solution.

Comment: @Pedro - How about you suggest a useful alternative as I'm sure it DOSE in fact work in all browsers and additionally keeps the HTML lean and semantic. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Mark - jslatts solution is the correct one and no it wont work in IE11 and just because it work's in the current browsers it is a very bad practice as you are using a side effect as functionality and if the implementation changes the side effect WILL stop working.

Comment: Instead of hiding the button text using the `text-indent: -9999px;` why not do this: `<%= Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", null, new { @class="classname" }) %>` Using a space for the name.

Answer (score 357):

I like to use Url.Action() and Url.Content() like this:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")'>
    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/MyLinkImage.png")' />
</a>
```

Strictly speaking, the Url.Content is only needed for pathing is not really part of the answer to your question.

Thanks to @BrianLegg for pointing out that this should use the new Razor view syntax. Example has been updated accordingly.

Comment: If you want a html helper for that: http://www.fsmpi.uni-bayreuth.de/~dun3/archives/asp-net-mvc-3-html-actionlink-image-imageactionlink-improved/483.html

Comment: This works perfectly. Just note that in MVC5 the syntax has changed and should be <a href='@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")'> and <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/MyLinkImage.png")' />. Thanks

Comment: it produced  it with NAN text? what to do

Answer (score 96):

Borrowing from Patrick's answer, I found that I had to do this:

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Users")';return false;">Cancel</button>
```

to avoid calling the form's post method.

Answer (score 50):

Call me simplistic, but I just do:

```
<a href="<%: Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") %>">
    <button>Button Text</button>
</a>
```

And you just take care of the hyperlink highlight.  Our users love it :)

Comment: @Ben one reason this doesn't have many votes is it was answered so much later than other answers. I was about to vote it up but tested out what @Slider345 said and can confirm this doesn't work as desired in IE 7 or 8. In any case, if you choose to use it, don't forget to set the css of the link (hover and active) to `text-decoration:none` to get rid of that stupid underline. This is necessary for some browsers (Firefox 11.0 for sure).

Comment: But you're not supposed to nest buttons inside a elements, visa versa. At least it's not a valid way of doing it in HTML 5

Comment: Yep, this doesn't work in even IE10, for the reasons Patrick explains.

Comment: No nesting of buttons inside of action element.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Answer (score 25):

Using bootstrap this is the shortest and cleanest approach to create a link to a controller action that appears as a dynamic button:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")' class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</a>
```

Or to use Html helpers:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Me", "Action", "Controller", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

Comment: I have to agree with the cleanness. 100.

Answer (score 16):

if you don't want to use a link, use button. you can add image to button as well:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Company")'" >
   Create New
   <img alt="New" title="New" src="~/Images/Button/plus.png">
</button>
```

**type="button"** performs your action instead of submitting form.

Answer (score 15):

Just simply :

```
<button onclick="@Url.Action("index", "Family", new {familyid = Model.FamilyID })">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: this still invokes the post method of the view for me, any idea why?

Comment: This isn't valid syntax. IE10 throws a JavaScript critical error with this line, "SCRIPT5017: Syntax error in regular expression".

Comment: Good answer, but without surrounding the `onclick` contents with `location.href` (so `onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(....)'"`) I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 15):

A late answer but this is how I make my ActionLink into a button. We're using Bootstrap in our project as it makes it convenient. Never mind the @T since its only an translator we're using.

```
@Html.Actionlink("Some_button_text", "ActionMethod", "Controller", "Optional parameter", "html_code_you_want_to_apply_to_the_actionlink");
```

The above gives a link like this and it looks as the picture below:

```
localhost:XXXXX/Firms/AddAffiliation/F0500
```

[image: picture demonstrating button with bootstrap]

In my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="section-header">
    <div class="title">
        @T("Admin.Users.Users")
    </div>
    <div class="addAffiliation">
        <p />
        @Html.ActionLink("" + @T("Admin.Users.AddAffiliation"), "AddAffiliation", "Firms", new { id = (string)@WorkContext.CurrentFirm.ExternalId }, new { @class="btn btn-primary" })
    </div>
</div>

}
```

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: Works cool! nice and simple, the htmlAttribute `new { @class="btn btn-primary" })` +one

Answer (score 12):

You can't do this with `Html.ActionLink`.  You should use `Url.RouteUrl` and use the URL to construct the element you want.

Comment: Hi, sorry I am very new to MVC. How would I use the Url.RouteURL to achieve the image?

Comment: What I meant is you can't generate a nested img tag (or button tag) with a simple call to ActionLink. Of course, CSS styling the a tag itself is a way to get around it, but nonetheless you can't get an img tag.

Answer (score 12):

A simple way to do make your Html.ActionLink into a button (as long as you have BootStrap plugged in - which you probably have) is like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Button text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

Answer (score 9):

`<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("NewCustomer", "Customers")'">Checkout >></button>`

Comment: This worked for me on IE10. This is a good solution if you simply want to use a button rather than an image, although having to use using inline JavaScript for a simple link is probably not ideal.

Comment: (and just to be sure, I tested it on Opera, Safari, Chrome and Firefox and it worked)

Answer (score 8):

Even later response, but I just ran into a similar issue and ended up writing my own [Image link HtmlHelper extension](http://blogs.aspiant.com/Mirko/2009/06/15/ASPNETMVCStronglyTypedActionLinkWithImages.aspx).

You can find an implementation of it on my blog in the link above.

Just added in case someone is hunting down an implementation.

Comment: Link appears to be inactive now

Answer (score 5):

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action(  "View", "Controller" )"><i class='fa fa-user'></i><span>Users View</span></a></li>
```

To display an icon with the link

Answer (score 4):

Do what Mehrdad says - or use the url helper from an `HtmlHelper` extension method like Stephen Walther describes [here](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/02/18/asp.net-mvc-tip-47-ndash-using-resolveurl-in-an-html.aspx) and make your own extension method which can be used to render all of your links.

Then it will be easy to render all links as buttons/anchors or whichever you prefer - and, most importantly, you can change your mind later when you find out that you actually prefer some other way of making your links.

Answer (score 3):

you can create your own extension method
take look at my implementation

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionImage(this HtmlHelper html, string action, object routeValues, string imagePath, string alt, object htmlAttributesForAnchor, object htmlAttributesForImage)
    {
        var url = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);

        // build the <img> tag
        var imgBuilder = new TagBuilder("img");
        imgBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", url.Content(imagePath));
        imgBuilder.MergeAttribute("alt", alt);
        imgBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributesForImage));
        string imgHtml = imgBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

        // build the <a> tag
        var anchorBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
        anchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", action != null ? url.Action(action, routeValues) : "#");
        anchorBuilder.InnerHtml = imgHtml; // include the <img> tag inside
        anchorBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributesForAnchor));

        string anchorHtml = anchorBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchorHtml);
    }
}
```

then use it in your view take look at my call

```
 @Html.ActionImage(null, null, "../../Content/img/Button-Delete-icon.png", Resource_en.Delete,
               new{//htmlAttributesForAnchor
                   href = "#",
                   data_toggle = "modal",
                   data_target = "#confirm-delete",
                   data_id = user.ID,
                   data_name = user.Name,
                   data_usertype = user.UserTypeID
               }, new{ style = "margin-top: 24px"}//htmlAttributesForImage
                    )
```

Answer (score 2):

For Material Design Lite and MVC:

```
<a class="mdl-navigation__link" href='@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")'>Link Name</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteMember", "Member", new { id = Model.MemberID }))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Delete Member" onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the member?');" />
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be lots of solutions on how to created a link that displays as an image, but none that make it appear to be a button.

There is only good way that I have found to do this. Its a little bit hacky, but it works.

What you have to do is create a button and a separate action link. Make the action link invisible using css. When you click on the button, it can fire the click event of the action link.

```
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="Search()" />
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Search", "ActionName", null, new AjaxOptions {}, new { id = "SearchLink", style="display:none;" })

function Search(){
    $("#SearchLink").click();
 }
```

It may be a pain in the butt to do this every time you add a link that needs to look like a button, but it does accomplish the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

use FORMACTION

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" formaction="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = Model.Id })" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`Url.Action()` will get you the bare URL for most overloads of `Html.ActionLink`, but I think that the `URL-from-lambda` functionality is only available through `Html.ActionLink` so far. Hopefully they'll add a similar overload to `Url.Action` at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Just found [this extension](http://dotnetdevdude.com/Blog/CommentView,guid,D1BC810E-CEE1-4A38-967E-AF7EB553831B.aspx#71a95cc2-ffe8-4a91-a238-efca693c25b8) to do it - simple and effective.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done it is to have the actionLink and the image seperately.
Set the actionlink image as hidden
and then added a jQuery trigger call. This is more of a workaround.

```
'<%= Html.ActionLink("Button Name", "Index", null, new { @class="yourclassname" }) %>'
<img id="yourImage" src="myImage.jpg" />
```

Trigger example:

```
$("#yourImage").click(function () {
  $('.yourclassname').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it without scripting:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <button type="submit" 
            class="btn btn-default" 
            title="Action description">Button Label</button>
}
```

Same, but with parameter and confirmation dialog:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", 
        new { paramName = paramValue }, 
        FormMethod.Get, 
        new { onsubmit = "return confirm('Are you sure?');" }))
{
    <button type="submit" 
            class="btn btn-default" 
            title="Action description">Button Label</button>
}
```