# Can I use an asp:Button like an Html.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ActionLink:

```
    <%: Html.ActionLink("MyAction", "MyAction") %>
```

I would like to use a button instead.  Something like this:

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="MyAction" />
```

What do I need to do to make clicking the button perform the same action as clicking the ActionLink?

Comment: A similar question has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596444/html-actionlink-as-a-button-or-an-image-not-a-link, but I'm hoping not to have to specify an image for an ActionLink, which seems to be the solution offered there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actionlink would be rather comparable to Hyperlinkbutton or Hyperlink controls in webforms. They all render a standard anchor element in html. So yes if you want to make it look like a button you should add some css sauce on top of it.

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("MyAction", "MyAction", null, new { @class = "button" } %>
```

and in the css file:

```
.button  {
    outline: 0; 
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    height: 2em;
    text-decoration: none !important; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:Green;
    border:1px solid Lime;
}
a.button { color:White;}
```

Note: I'm a developer so somewhat design challenged. Playing around with border-left, -right, -bottom and -top you can make it look nicer.

Update after the first comment:

Other alternatives, which don't look that nice to me, are:

```
<% Using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home")) {%>

    <input type="submit" value="About" />

<% } %>
```

Or with the Button control:

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">

    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="sfsf" Text ="Go!" PostBackUrl="/Home/About" />

</form>
```

Comment: Is there no way to use the actual button control to trigger the action?

Comment: Ah, that last one with the PostBackUrl is what I was trying to do.  I think I had just been getting the url wrong.  This works for me now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and just wrote what I wanted in html.

```
<input type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="document.location = '/Product/Index'; return false;" />
```

I would have liked to use a type="button", but since that used a different style then i made it a submit button and added return false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an actual Ajax `button` element, rather than a styling hack or mini-form or JQuery, it is also possible but a little involved. It is a shame that MS has not yet chosen to add an ActionButton to both the Html and Ajax helpers as the differences are actually very minor when you remove the duplication of private support methods (you would only need the `ActionButton` and `GenerateButton` methods shown below).

The end result is you can have real buttons that trigger like ajax action links:

### e.g.

```
@Ajax.ActionButton("Delete", "Delete", "document", 
     new { id = ViewBag.Id }, 
     new AjaxOptions() 
     { 
         Confirm="Do you really want to delete this file?", 
         HttpMethod = "Get", 
         UpdateTargetId = "documentlist" }, 
         new { id = "RefreshDocuments" 
     })
```

### 1. Create an AjaxHelper extension

The code below is based on a decompile of the AjaxExtensions class as many of the required helper methods are not exposed on HtmlHelper.

```
public static partial class AjaxExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionButton(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, string buttonText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValuesBlah, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, object htmlAttributesBlah)
    {
        // Convert generic objects to specific collections
        RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValuesBlah);
        RouteValueDictionary htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributesBlah);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(buttonText))
            throw new ArgumentException("Button text must be provided");
        string targetUrl = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl((string)null, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, ajaxHelper.RouteCollection, ajaxHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, true);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(GenerateButton(ajaxHelper, buttonText, targetUrl, AjaxExtensions.GetAjaxOptions(ajaxOptions), htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static string GenerateButton(AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, string linkText, string targetUrl, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", linkText);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes<string, object>(htmlAttributes);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", targetUrl);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("type", "button");
        if (ajaxHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled)
            tagBuilder.MergeAttributes<string, object>(ajaxOptions.ToUnobtrusiveHtmlAttributes());
        else
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("onclick", AjaxExtensions.GenerateAjaxScript(ajaxOptions, "Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), {0});"));
        return tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }

    private static string GenerateAjaxScript(AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, string scriptFormat)
    {
        string str = ajaxOptions.ToJavascriptString();
        return string.Format((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, scriptFormat, new object[1] { str });
    }

    private static AjaxOptions GetAjaxOptions(AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)
    {
        if (ajaxOptions == null)
            return new AjaxOptions();
        else
            return ajaxOptions;
    }

    public static string ToJavascriptString(this AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("{");
        stringBuilder.Append(string.Format((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " insertionMode: {0},", new object[1]
        {
             ajaxOptions.InsertionModeString()
        }));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.PropertyStringIfSpecified("confirm", ajaxOptions.Confirm));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.PropertyStringIfSpecified("httpMethod", ajaxOptions.HttpMethod));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.PropertyStringIfSpecified("loadingElementId", ajaxOptions.LoadingElementId));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.PropertyStringIfSpecified("updateTargetId", ajaxOptions.UpdateTargetId));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.PropertyStringIfSpecified("url", ajaxOptions.Url));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.EventStringIfSpecified("onBegin", ajaxOptions.OnBegin));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.EventStringIfSpecified("onComplete", ajaxOptions.OnComplete));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.EventStringIfSpecified("onFailure", ajaxOptions.OnFailure));
        stringBuilder.Append(ajaxOptions.EventStringIfSpecified("onSuccess", ajaxOptions.OnSuccess));
        --stringBuilder.Length;
        stringBuilder.Append(" }");
        return ((object)stringBuilder).ToString();
    }

    public static string InsertionModeString(this AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)
    {
        switch (ajaxOptions.InsertionMode)
        {
            case InsertionMode.Replace:
                return "Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace";
            case InsertionMode.InsertBefore:
                return "Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.insertBefore";
            case InsertionMode.InsertAfter:
                return "Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.insertAfter";
            default:
                return ((int)ajaxOptions.InsertionMode).ToString((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }

    public static string EventStringIfSpecified(this AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, string propertyName, string handler)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(handler))
            return string.Empty;
        return string.Format((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " {0}: Function.createDelegate(this, {1}),",
            new object[2]
              {
                propertyName,
                handler
              });
    }

    public static string PropertyStringIfSpecified(this AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyValue))
            return string.Empty;
        string str = propertyValue.Replace("'", "\\'");
        return string.Format((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " {0}: '{1}',",
            new object[2]
              {
                propertyName,
                str
              });
    }
}
```

### 2. Modify jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Only a small change is required to the JQuery of jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js to accept the new button object, as it is very close to begin with. First the selector needs to accept buttons as well as links and then the href needs to come from an attribute so than a non-link can provide it (not strictly browser compliant but works for now).

```
$(document).on("click", "input[data-ajax=true],a[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        asyncRequest(this, {
            url: $(this).attr("href"),
            type: "GET",
            data: []
        });
    });
```

*Note: this is using the latest version of everything as at the date of answering (MVC 5)