# Find broken controller actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I find broken Html.ActionLinks?

e.g. Find `Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewCustomer", "Customer")` where `CustomerController.ViewCustomer()` no longer exists.

Comment: By doing a search in your views for "ViewCustomer"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use strongly-typed action links from [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RedirectToAction&referringTitle=Documentation).

```
<%: Html.ActionLink<Home>(c => c.Index()) %>
```

These will break at compile-time when you remove a referenced controller method, if you are using compiled views.

Comment: Are these "strongly-typed action links" part of the ASP.NET MVC 3 framework? I've never seen this built in feature... Can you add a link pointing to the documentation?

Comment: That's the thing, I was almost ready to redo my entire project to strongly typed links (given it works in every scenario, not only `ActionLink`), but tried first - it's not built in, you have to install `MvcFutures`. People on this site say this package has issues - bugs and performance. I personally didn't check it, but `T4MVC` is well tested and has been working for years. I stick with my answer and `T4MVC` for now.

Comment: They are part of MVC3, but part of futures. They were part of T4MVC, which is now part of MvcContrib - see http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RedirectToAction&referringTitle=Documentation for the docs

Comment: @IanRoutledge This is what they say on their website: 
T4MVC is still part of MvcContrib, but was moved to a separate CodePlex project for convenience. Link: http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC

Comment: Seems like generics-based approach above is a different mechanism than the T4MVC approach. Both MvcContrib and T4MVC are available through  NuGet. Personally I like the generics-based approach because it avoids the T4 compilation step.

Comment: True. People say its significantly slower performing (lambda expressions). Anyway, right tool for the right job is always the case.

Answer (score 2):

If you looking for systematic approach install (can use NuGet) and apply [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/).

I did it to my own project - all your magic strings (not only action links, but everything that require strings) disappear across your application. You end up using **only strongly typed** helpers to eliminate the use of literal strings.

In your case in particular

```
@Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewCustomer", "Customer")
```

will become

```
@Html.ActionLink("Externalize me as well!", MVC.Customer.ViewCustomer())
```

and if you externalize the one suggested, it will become what you looking for:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Config.ViewLabel, MVC.Customer.ViewCustomer())
```

*Isn't it a beauty?*
I think this supposed to be de facto standard rather than "stringified" approach.

Look to what it does to your project:
In Views:

```
@Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Customer.Views.YourView)
```

In controllers:

```
return View(Views.YourView);
```

or

```
RedirectToAction(MVC.Home.MyAction().AddRouteValues(Request.QueryString));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems a bit old (it was designed for MVC 1.0 and 2.0). While I (sorta) like the syntax, I think strongly-typed action links are now the canonical way to do it, and you can use those without having to type fully-qualified names.

Comment: @RobertHarvey does it work on all levels (that I just listed at least) or only on action links? Cause I do like it too, its just T4MVC seems to be more systematic... Curious. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertHarvey read about strongly typed actionlinks - its much hated by the community, mainly for performance issues, but while magic strings are obviously significantly faster, T4MVC is the tradeoff between those two. I'd say T4MVC is the way to go - strongly typed and systematic. Thanks for pointing out!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620832/considerations-for-strongly-typed-actionlink

Comment: Hey, it doesn't even work out of the box. I thought since its canonical, its part of the environment and I missed something, but its not there, have to install additional package. While that package is probably valuable. its job is other than providing strongly typed things. Its rather side business, while T4MVC is dedicated to specifically that. I think its a no brainer. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111212/t4mvc-or-mvcfutures-for-strongly-typed-links-in-views

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution does not answer the question. Here's my solution (not sure if it requires Resharper or not).

1. Click on any broken action (create one if you must)
2. Hover the red bulb
3. Hover Inspection MVC
4. Hover Find similar issues in >
5. Click custom scope
6. Restrict your scope (it might tell you 10000's of quality issues)
7. Search "resolve action" in the results