# mvc3 Html.ActionLink as image not as text

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
<div class="orderby_name">
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "DisplayCategory", "Categories", new { articleSortBy = "Name", articleSortType = "asc" }, null)
</div>
```

i am lookin in razor if exist ImageLink. Now i have @Html.ActionLink and becouse i do not have any text name i can not click on it. I want to have image as link.

How can i make image as link in razor?

Comment: You have to create custom helper. Try this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111110/mvc3-actionlink-with-images-but-without-mvcfutures

Comment: Here is an example of what you are looking for:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896439/action-image-mvc3-razor

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html.ActionLink as a button or an image, not a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596444/html-actionlink-as-a-button-or-an-image-not-a-link)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The built-in helper cannot do that.

You need to create an ordinary `<a href="@Url.Action(...)">` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this code is helpful

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Index")'>
                        <img src='@Url.Content("../../Content/Images/head.jpg")' alt="Home Page">
                    </a>        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it looks like there is a way.. if you add a CSS rule to the htmlAttributes, as is shown in the top answer of this post:
[Html.ActionLink as a button or an image, not a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596444/html-actionlink-as-a-button-or-an-image-not-a-link)

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net mvc 3 the code you have works with the single space for the link text, just add a class name that points to an image (the class name below points to a font awesome image):

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "ActionName", "ControllerName",
new {UniqueId = item.UniqueId},
new { @class = "fa fa-download", @title = "Download the document" })
```

And add some css to prevent the image from having an underline:

```
a.fa
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```