# How to display a URL stored image from database in ASP.NET Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, razor

The database involved includes two entities that are `ID` of type int & `ImagePath` of type text. The `ID` holds an auto incremented number and the `ImagePath` holds the URL of a specific image. Currently I've managed to display all images found in the database with the below code.

**Index.cshtml**

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagePath)
    <img src="~/Images/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagePath)" />
```

**ImageController.cs**

```
  public class ImageController : Controller
    {
        private ImageDBContext db = new ImageDBContext();

          public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Images.ToList());
        }
```

I would like to display a specific image and not all the images found in the database. Can someone kindly help me out in displaying a specific URL stored image from the database by `ID`? *(ie. Display Image from* `ImagePath` *through a called ID in the .cshtml)*

Highly appreciate your time and help. Thank you.

#### UPDATE:

Wrote the below code down in order to Display image from `db.image` table having chosen `ImageID` = 2 to represent the related url stored image.

***ImageController.cs***

```
  public ActionResult Index(int ImageID = 2)
        {

            return View(db.Images.Where(img => img.ID == ImageID).ToList());
        }
```

***Index.cshtml***

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagePath)
         <img src="~/Images/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagePath)"/>
```

Moving forward  I would like to select the `ImageID` from the *Index.cshtml* instead of `int ImageID = 2` from the `public ActionResult Index()` in the controller. Was thinking of adding `ImageID == 2` in the `@html.DisplayFor` but don't know how. Any ideas how to select the `ImageID` from the index.cshtml code to represent the image related?*

***END GOAL***
Having the below `<img src=""/>` replaced to call `imagePath` from the given `ID`.

```
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/vellanevets" target="_blank"> <img src="images/social/instagram.png" /></a>
    <a href="http://instagram.com/nevetsvella/" target="_blank"> <img src="images/social/instagram.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="http://vimeo.com/user16587212" target="_blank"> <img src="images/social/vimeo.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="mailto:steven.vella93@gmail.com" target="_blank"> <img src="images/social/email.png" alt="" /></a>
        }
```

Comment: Which step of this very broad question causes you problem: get id of image to action, query item by ID from DB, return image as stream, something else?

Comment: you need to use `@Url.Action` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436375/mvc3-html-actionlink-as-image-not-as-text

Comment: check out the new update maybe it clarifies my end goal

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to return specific documents in your database. Assuming your data column is named `ID` you can do the following.

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    private ImageDBContext db = new ImageDBContext();

    public ActionResult Index(int intValue){

    var imagesId = db.Images.Where(img -> img.ID == intValue).ToList();

    return View(imagesId);

    }
}
```

This will return all your images with Id equal to intValue.

As an aside, it seems you are only attempting to retrieve 1 document, if that's the case you can (and should) use FirstOrDefault, like so `var imageWithId = db.Images.FirstOrDefault(img -> img.ID == intValue);`

**Edit for Update+Comments:**

It seems you wish to act on information that is client side, in your Index View. There are multiple ways of doing this, one is to reload the page by passing back a value to your controller which will pass the correct model (in your case, an image) to your View.

If you wish to replace values with values in your model, you can iterate through your model and replace the css property. Select the elements with the srcs you wish to replace then use.

```
var imagePath = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ImagePath));
$(this).attr("src", imagePath);
```

Using JQuery to reload your page with new Image:

```
$(document).on('event', '.selector', function() {
     //Set your ID to the Id property of the element   
    var idToPass = this.id;
    clicked
    //This will simulate an HTTP request, your action will return your View with your image
window.location.replace('@Url.Action("Index", "Image")?ImageID=' + idToPass) 
});
```

Replace event with the event you wish to trigger the reload. `'click'` for example. Replace the selector with a class you give all the elements you wish to be clickable.

Note: Careful! Using `on.('click)` on anchors can lead to interesting results.

You can also use AJAX to dynamically pass information to your page without reloading.

Comment: Cheers for your help mate. Can you have a look at the update I've written ?

Comment: I don't understand the update completely. If you wish to pass a parameter to a method you should use `public ActionResult Index(int ImageID)` and then call Index method with whatever Id you wish to pass, such as `Index(2)` or `Index(9001)` to retrieve the image with those Ids. What is the event you wish to capture to redirect to a specific Id? I.E. Where are you getting the Id number from?

Comment: The 'ID' is obtained from the table through the connected server. I wish to display the image in 'ImagePath' field from the related 'ID' by selecting the 'ImageID' from the index.cshtml and not the .ImageController.cs.

Comment: Posted an update. The first part will be enough to get you on the right pass to replacing your srcs with ALL images in your model, and the second part will help you reload the page with a new image if you wish to do that. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have simply to filter your images in your query

```html
public class ImageController : Controller
    {
        private ImageDBContext db = new ImageDBContext();

          public ActionResult Index()
        {
            [.. some code to decide the id ..]

            return View(db.Images
              .Where(x => x.ID = [myId]
              .ToList());
        }
```

Comment: Appreciate your assistance. Can you check out the Update I've added?