# MVC - button to fire an Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Link Text", 
    "RefreshTestStatus2", 
    "refresh",
    new AjaxOptions { 
        UpdateTargetId = "status", 
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore })
```

But I would like to use something that looks like a submit button to fire it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Judy

Answer (score 9):

I decided to implement it as an Ajax form.

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm( 
  "RefreshTestStatus2", 
  "refresh",
  new AjaxOptions { 
    UpdateTargetId = "status", 
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore }))
{
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Link Text" />
}
```

I think it's safe to say it's not as clean an Ajax.ActionLink, but gives you an input button.

Comment: +1, answers the question directly! 
a submit button is ment to submit a form, hence, Ajax form!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use some css to make the link look like a button

such as this [example](http://devgrow.com/super-simple-css-buttons/)

also see the related [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596444/html-actionlink-as-a-button-or-an-image-not-a-link)