# How to create an Image hyperlink when using Ajax.ActionLink and Html.ActionLink that is to get <a><img/></a>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to have an image instead of clickable text and using MVC helpers. Trying the following in vain, also tried toying with MvcHtmlString.Create() which gives an error:

```
                        @Ajax.ActionLink(Url.Content("~/Content/extremepc/rightarrow.png"), "Index", "Store", new { category = Model.category, page = Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage + 1 }, 
               new AjaxOptions
   {
       UpdateTargetId = "Everything",

       Url = Url.Action("StoreContent", "Store", new { category = Model.category, page = Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage + 1 })
   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to render the link manually.
This might require a lot of effort with your `Ajax` helper methods, so you'd be best to wrap it in an `AjaxHelper` Extension method.

See this very similar question for several similar solutions:
[Html.ActionLink as a button or an image, not a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596444/html-actionlink-as-a-button-or-an-image-not-a-link)

It would be awesome if the `Html.ActionLink` (and all other helpers for that matter) would allow the `label` parameter to accept a `HtmlString` ... I'm actually surprised that's not already the case!
However, since the MVC framework is open-source, it actually wouldn't be too difficult to copy the `AjaxHelper` methods, and modify them to use `HtmlString` instead of `String`.