# MVC3 WebGrid - @Url.Action using image button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I got a problem that actually I do not yet solved. For some reasons I had a request to replace the text used in Html.ActionLink with a more visual design using images as button inside a WebGrid for the usuale operations like modify, duplicate, publish and delete. 
Reading I have tried many ways but none led me to the final stage:

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, new List<string>(), canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
        @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
        htmlAttributes: new { id = "DataTable" },
        headerStyle: "header",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns:
        grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("Description", header: "Description"),
        grid.Column("DateCreation", header: "Creation Date"),
        grid.Column("CompanyOwner", header: "Company"),
        grid.Column("Owner", header: "User"),
        grid.Column("Status", header: "Status"),
        grid.Column("Action", header: "Action", 
                          format: (item) => @Url.Action("publish", 
                                                        "PublishItem",  
                                                        new { id = item.ID })))
        );
    }
```

To do that I start with a model created with a linq to entities where I added the column Action, the one that I want to use to place my buttons. How do I place the images to work as buttons as I done in a normal table:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("PublishPill", new { id = item.ID })">
<img src="../../Images/world_32px.png", alt="Edit" title="Publish" border="0" /></a>
```

Comment: See this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596444/html-actionlink-as-a-button-or-an-image-not-a-link

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`grid.Column(header: "Contraseña", format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("ChangePassword", "Home", new { id = item.Identification })" ><img src="../../Content/images/password.png" alt="" style="border:none;" /></a></text>, style: "colOperation")`