# Put a logo with @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

If you use ASP.NET MVC 4 template to generate a default web project, you will find the code.

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo", "Index", "Home")</p>
            </div>
```

Now I have an existing image "logo.jpg", I want to insert it in the linktext position, how to?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596444/html-actionlink-as-a-button-or-an-image-not-a-link)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit misleading, since you can't do this directly.

As rikitikitik's link suggests, one thing you can do is keep the `ActionLink` as is, but give it a class and then apply CSS rules to turn the link into an image.

Alternatively you can just use your own HTML `<img>` tag or write your own HTML helper to generate image-link combinations.

Comment: So you mean Microsoft should improve it for confusion?

Comment: I'd say they should improve it for clarification ;)

Comment: I dunno, IMHO the confusion needs to be improved as well. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to display an Image and there was no use of link for me.
This is what i did:

Totally removed the @Html.ActionLink and simply used the <p> as a place holder so that my existing css can bind to it properly:

```
<div class="float-left">    
    <p class="site-title" ></p>
</div>
```

Now I opened my site.css and replaced the css for site-title as:

```
/* site title
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-title {
    color: #c8c8c8;
    font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    margin: 0;

    background: url("../images/logo.png") no-repeat center left; 
    display: block;
    height: 84px; 
    width: 512px;
}
```

Note that i have to use **../images** instead of **~/images**

Also i simply deleted more css in same site.css for 
.site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active

It's totally up to you if you want to keep additional css for additional actions.

Thanks and Regards
Anugrah