# Creating Action Links Without A View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-ajax

Right now I am trying to create a link that, upon the user clicking, would change a Boolean without calling up it's own view.  Whenever I click the link though, it sends me to a view that doesn't exist. Can anyone find what I'm doing wrong to make sure it stays in the current view and performs the action?

The cshtml:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Hide",
"Hide",
"Manager",
new { id = item.MenuID },
new AjaxOptions
{
HttpMethod = "POST",
OnSuccess = "function() { alert('The item has been hidden')"
})
```

The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Hide(int id)
{
    Menu menu = db.Menus.Find(id);
    if (menu == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    menu.Display = false;
    db.Entry(menu).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Also, a slightly related side question, is there a way to make the link into a button?

Comment: Regarding the side question (making it a button), see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596444/html-actionlink-as-a-button-or-an-image-not-a-link

Comment: what scripts are you referencing on your page?

Comment: make sure you have the ajax unobtrusive reference included on your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your page is missing one of the following script. Make sure you reference them all:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Huh, completely forgot to do the script includes.  Fixed it right up.  Now to find a way to make it refresh the table after the change has been made.

Answer (score 0):

Use `void` instead of `ActionResult` for the Hide method in your controller (and remove the "return" clause, of course).