# how to display vertical text on button or add function like Solution Explore in Visual studio on right side

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to display vertical text on button or add function like Solution Explore in Visual studio on right side.   and show a pop up on mouse over same as visual studio show text

Answer (score 0):

Allthough I'm having a hard time understandig your question(s):
I think you might want to consider using an image with vertical text as button.
This is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596444/html-actionlink-as-a-button-or-an-image-not-a-link).

A pop up on a mouseover event? You mean a tooltip showing on mouseover?
Well that can easily be done with the "alt" attribute for images.