# Link Text attribute not available in javascript from Action Link extension method MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am calling a controller/action from an action link to display the results in a partial view within bootstrap modal dialog. All is working as expected until the user requested the action link not to be text but to be an image.

I thought the best solution would be to create an actionlinkimage extension helper, which was based on the one Basheer posted as a solution on this question [Html.ActionLink as a button or an image, not a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596444/html-actionlink-as-a-button-or-an-image-not-a-link]) and it works brilliantly :

```
 public static class ActionImageHelper
    {

        public static IHtmlString ImageActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string action, string controller, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes, string imageSrc)
        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
            var img = new TagBuilder("img");
            img.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(imageSrc));
            var anchor = new TagBuilder("a") { InnerHtml = img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing) };
            anchor.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(action, controller, routeValues);
            anchor.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchor.ToString());

        }

    }
```

However switching the standard @HtmlAction link to this extension helper i now cannot access the text attribute of the link in javascript , so when I attempt to extract the text to display as my dialog title it comes in blank , see javascript here :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").on("click", "a.dialog-window", null, function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var $link = $(this);        
            var title = $link.text();   //***Using the text prop for the title 
            $('#myModal .modal-title').html(title);

            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
            else {

                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $('#myModal .te').html(data);
                    $('#myModal').modal();
                });

            }

        });
    });

</script>
```

As you can see on the 6th line , where I attempt to get the text from the link. This now comes back as empty.
I have attempted to add the text property in the extension method but with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

**Using:**
jquery3.1.1
Bootstrap v3.3.7
.NET 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working in the end by changing my Extension helper to the following :

```
   public static class ActionImageHelper
{

    public static IHtmlString ImageActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string dialogTitle, string linkText, string action,
        string controller, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes, string imageSrc)
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var img = new TagBuilder("img");
        img.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(imageSrc));
        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("a") { InnerHtml = img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing) };
        builder.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(action, controller, routeValues);
        builder.Attributes["title"] = dialogTitle;
        builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());

    }

}
```

I added an extra parameter **dialogTitle** in which I pass in the title , and then set the title attributes within the extension method to set the title.

And changed the javascript function to then read from this attribute :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").on("click", "a.dialog-window", null, function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var $link = $(this);
            //var title = $link.text();   // Using the text prop for the title
            var title = $(this).attr('title') //Now use the title attribute 
            $('#myModal .modal-title').html(title);

            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
            else {

                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $('#myModal .contents').html(data);
                    $('#myModal').modal();
                });

            }

        });
    });

</script>
```

Perhaps this is not the most elegant solution, maybe someone has a better solution, but at least it means that the Extension menthod and javascript are re-usable and generic (i.e. no hard coded title) and the title is controlled when calling the ImageActionLink control.

Here is how I call the ImageActionLink :

```
  @Html.ImageActionLink("Edit Client:", "Edit", "Edit", "Client", new { id = item.i_client_id },
               new
               {

                   @class = "dialog-window",
               }, "~/Content/images/icons/open-icon-green-16.png")
```